# How to set type for particular item in each loop in svelte?

Tags: svelte

I wanted to set type to every item in an array while using `#each` loop. I want to achieve something like:

```
type User={
  name:string;
  id:number;
}

let userData:User[]=[{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"Harry"}]
```

and use it like

```
{#each userData as user:User,index}
  <h1>ID: {item.id}
  <h1>User name: {user.name}</h1>
{/each}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think svelte is "smart" to do that for you, not need to state the type of the element of array.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This answer is short enough to be a comment, rather than an answer.